# Return functions within functions containing attribute

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to `Javascript` and I am trying to understand a piece of code.

The code goes like this:

```
function abcd (x){
    return function(v){
        return x && v ;
    }
}
```

and it is called like below:

```
abcd(false);
```

Here, where does the compiler get the value of `v`, the attribute of return function from.

Comment: It doesn't. `abcd` returns a new function which needs to be called for `v` to have a value. Since that function isn't called in your example, to `v` doesn't even exist. FYI, `x` and `v` are *parameters* of the functions, not *attributes*.

Comment: Well, `abcd` returns a function, so `abcd(false)` is a function — exactly this function receives the argument `v`. Example: `abcd(false)(true);` returns `false`.

Comment: It is called function currying your function is partially executed and return another function so that you can chain it like myfunction(param1)(param2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a way of constructing functions that allows partial application of function's argument.
It is a curried function. You can check this [**LINK**](http://javascript.crockford.com/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/) to know more about currying

So on `abcd(false);` will return the inner function,

```
return function(v){
        return x && v ;
    }
```

But `abcd(false)(false)` will return `false`.

You can slightly modify this above function for understanding

```
function abcd (x){
    return function(v){
        return x + v ;
    }
}
var _a = abcd(1)(1); // will log 2
```